# rsync specific directories

Tags: rsync, wildcards, file-copy

Below are the directories of my directory structure.

I only want to run `rsync` on the content under the archive directory of any subdirectory and exclude everything else:

```
./
ap/
ap/aploader/
ap/aploader/archive/
ap/as400/
ap/as400/archive/
ce/
ce/archive/
edi/
edi/810/
edi/810/archive/
fin/
fin/adp/
fin/adp/archive/
gl/
gl/adp/
gl/adp/archive/
gl/as400/
gl/as400/archive/
gl/dcb/
gl/dcb/archive/
om/
om/pricelist/
om/pricelist/archive/
om/sygma/
om/sygma/archive/
```

The source and destination directories have the same directory structure but only archive directory need to `rsync`.

For example:

Everything under `/xx/inbound/om/pricelist/archive` needs to be copied to `/yy/inbound/om/pricelist/archive` 
 and
`xx/inbound/om/sygma/archive` needs to be copied to 
`/yy/inbound/om/sygma/archive`, and so on...

I tried the following which doesn't work as I want it to:

```
rsync --include '**archive/***' --exclude '*' -avzh -avzh /xx/inbound/ /yy/inbound
```

Comment: try replacing the order of the include and exclude, first exclude everything, then include only the archive folders.

Comment: Even that don't work

Answer (score 4):

I think the only thing you're missing is to initially include all directories leading to the archive dirs, ie. also `--include='*/'`. This is because excluding a directory (with '*') excludes everything below it

```
rsync --include='*/' --include='**archive/***' --exclude='*' -avzh /xx/inbound/ /yy/inbound
```

Apart from that, you shouldn't need 2 sets of `'-avzh'`